# Scala filter function needs case?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to scala/spark, I'm curious about if the `case` is really required?

```
pairs.filter{case (key, value) => value.length < 20}
```

Comment: you need case just for pattern matching. but there is '_' that you can use to match the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're destructuring the tuple. Thus, you have to use the pattern matching syntax, which uses the `case` keyword.

```
pairs.filter{case (key, value) => value.length < 20}
```

This calls filter with a function of one argument, a 2-tuple.

```
pairs.filter{(key, value) => value.length < 20}
```

This calls filter with a function of two arguments. This is not the correct type of function and will produce a type error.

Comment: The second syntax is only available since 2.12 as I remember.

Comment: @GáborBakos The second syntax doesn't work at all in Scala. Tuple deconstruction will only be available in dotty, and that won't need curly brackets.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thanks for the correction, I remembered seeing it somewhere, but it seems I'll have to wait longer to use that syntax.

Answer (score 4):

It is not required. That syntax is for partial functions the following would also work:

```
pairs.filter(tuple => tuple._2.length < 20)
```

Or equivalently:

```
pairs.filter(_._2.length < 20)
```